# How can i update the data within my app without having the user update the app in the playstore

Tags: database, google-app-engine, web-applications

I'm taking a break from simple game development to do something totally different. I would like to create an android/ios app (something like a news app and new technology app) that i can daily update the data in it without having the user update the app every day within the playstore. My question(s) would be , what would be the easiest and less confusing way to do so. And would I be required to have a website to correlate it to and just sync data to the app.
I've researched for days and I have gotten some leads but none that really clarifies how it's done. If someone could show me a step by step or tutorials on this topic it'll be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to make the data available as a web service and have the app go fetch the data.

Comment: By any chance would you have a tutorial or example page to do this?